# How to transfer an object's methods to string in Python?

Tags: python

How to make an object to return string that anything after the object name?

```
a = AnyMethodToString()
print(a.b.c[1].d["e"].f)
=> 'b.c[1].d["e"].f'
```

Comment: You want `a.b` to be `'b'` and `a.b.c` to be `'b.c'`, but the string `'b'` has no `c` attribute. Whatever underlying goal you're trying to accomplish by doing this, pick a different design.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica More accurately, they want `a.b` to print as `b`, which just means it is an object with a `__str__` method which returns the string `'b'`. That is quite feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting challenge, this is possible by writing a class with `__getattr__` and `__getitem__` methods. To keep things simple, I made the variable `s` part of a closure instead of an attribute, otherwise `self.s` could ambiguously refer to either the string or the `__getattr__` method.

For bonus points, the `__call__` method allows you to put method calls in there, too.

```py
def magic(s=''):
    class Magic:
        def __str__(self):
            return s
        def __repr__(self):
            return s
        def __getattr__(self, i):
            return magic('{0}.{1}'.format(s, i).lstrip('.'))
        def __getitem__(self, i):
            return magic('{0}[{1!r}]'.format(s, i))
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            a = [repr(x) for x in args]
            a += ['{0}={1!r}'.format(k, x) for k, x in kwargs.items()]
            return magic('{0}({1})'.format(s, ', '.join(a)))
    return Magic()
```

Usage:

```py
>>> a = magic('a')
>>> a.b
a.b
>>> a.b.c
a.b.c
>>> a.b.c[1].d["e"].f
a.b.c[1].d['e'].f
>>> a.foo('bar', baz=4)
a.foo('bar', baz=4)
```

Or without the `a.` part:

```py
>>> a = magic()
>>> a.b
b
>>> a.b.c
b.c
>>> a.b.c[1].d["e"].f
b.c[1].d['e'].f
>>> a.foo('bar', baz=4)
foo('bar', baz=4)
```

Comment: Very cool, could you explain how the getitem is working here wrt format ?

Comment: @Manakin Basically `__getitem__` is the method which gets called when you access `a[i]`, so it returns a new `magic` object with the string `a[i]` where the `!r` part converts `i` to its "repr" string (so you get quotes around strings, for example).

Comment: awesome thanks! also nice to see a fellow brummy on here!